# make div appear depending on multiple text inputs using jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to make a div fade in depending on the whether value (postcode) entered into an input includes a predefined set of characters. I have managed to get it to work for one value but I would like it to work on multiple inputs as eventually there will be multiple postcodes. It would also be good if I could make it ignore spaces and cases so I could just put one value for each postcode and not five as I have done here:

```
$(".postcode-checker").click(function()
{
 var name = $("#postcode-form input").val();
 if(name != '')
{
   if ($("#postcode-form input").val().indexOf("BS2 9","bs2 9","BS29","bs29","Bs2 9","Bs29") > -1)
   {
    $('#bpwdp').fadeIn(500);
   }
 }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x8NwW/

If you enter 'BS2 9' it works but none of the following values e.g. 'bs2 9' don't.

I've been reading around and I'm not sure if a regular expression, .indexOf, or .match  would be the answer but I'm not really sure how to implement them in this context.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the whitespace, convert to uppercase and then you can just compare the start of the string with `BS29`:

```
$(".postcode-checker").click(function() {
   var name = $("#postcode-form input").val().replace(/\s+/g, '').toUpperCase();    
   $('#bpwdp')[name.match(/^BS29/) ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut'](500);
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8NwW/9/)

Comment: Thank you for this. It's exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way I can add extra postcodes? I tried `(/^BS29/^BS30)` but that didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, you'd just do `/^[BS29|AB12|BC13]/` etc.

Comment: Mr Onecan - It now seems to fade the div in if you add any character from any of the listed postcodes e.g. just the letter B or just the letter S. Any ideas? 

http://jsfiddle.net/x8NwW/11/

Comment: @ItalianDavid: ahh good catch. Just remove the `[]` and it should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/x8NwW/15/

Answer (score 3):

Your if condition is not correct as `indexof` is correct so use the below code:

```
var postcode = ["BS2 9","bs2 9","BS29","bs29","Bs2 9","Bs29"];
if (postcode.indexOf($("#postcode-form input").val()) > -1){...}
```

The right syntax of indexOf is be :

```
array1.indexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex]);
^^^              ^^^ data that you will search
data from which you search
```

Tutorial is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff679977%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).